# Providing sh file as input parameter to ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, processbuilder

My code is like this

```
final String[] cmdArray = {
 "sh", "./invoke_payment_files_generator.sh",
 String.valueOf(paymentBatchId)
 };


 final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cmdArray); 

processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
```

but it failed to read the file with error: no such file or directory..
Can you please give me the possible ways to provide sh file as input parameter to ProcessBuilder.

Comment: Set directory with `processbuilder.directory(String)` to the directory where your sh file is located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use `/bin/sh` instead of just `sh`.

Furthermore, as @user432 already mentioned, you may want to explicitly set the `ProcessBuilder`'s working directory using its `directory(String)` method if your shell script is not in the Java application's working directory. Alternatively, you could specify the absolute path to your shell script, not just `./`.